# php special character trim

Tags: php, trim

I have a set of strings like below :

```
fw-sophi.watcon.-.120
d-elain.heckop.-.121
sim.boosh.-.134
bh.-.elain.heckop.-.244
```

How would I trim the following set of strings to return only the middle section?
expected return:

```
sophi.watcon
elain.heckop
sim.boosh
elain.heckop
```

It isn't practical to `trim()` the strings manually as there are a lot, how would I do this Programmatically ?

Comment: It's complicated, you have distinct patterns to each string, they're not similar. If it can be done, mostly will be done using some `preg_` function.

Comment: @AlanMachado Mind showing me an example of how I would trim one of them i.e the last one. I'm not too knowledgeable on `preg_` from that I can then create some conditions and trim the strings.

Comment: you can use explode('.-.', $value) and getting the first part, or directly $val_result = explode('.-.', $value)[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no other patterns, this should be sufficient:

```
$input = 'fw-sophi.watcon.-.120
d-elain.heckop.-.121
sim.boosh.-.134
bh.-.elain.heckop.-.244';

if (preg_match_all('~(?<key>\w+\.\w+)~', $input, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches['key']);
}
```

Resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sophi.watcon
    [1] => elain.heckop
    [2] => sim.boosh
    [3] => elain.heckop
)
```

Pattern explanation:

```
~                 #pattern start 
(                 #start group to capture matched result
    ?<key>        #give a name to group. see $matches['key'].
    \w+           #one or more alphanumeric characters
    \.            #dot character. we need to escape it with \
    \w+           #one or more alphanumeric characters
)                 #end group
~                 #pattern end
x
```

Comment: Hey what is `$matches`?

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r the array containing matched results. see: http://php.net/preg_match_all